# Google Maps API Web Service Parameters

Tags: php, json, web-services, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I'm trying to use the new API for geocoding at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Chiavari+Via+Preli+30&key=....

I have a few questions about it:

1. I'm interested in a mere information about latitude and longitude.
   How can i isolate this information? (I need to add it into a php
   script)
2. Is there a way (web-services parameters) to only get what I need?
3. Using this web service, is it possible to calculate the distance from
   2 points not only as a line, but also as a road path?

Comment: found this for js 
---
for (i = 0; i < myJSONResult.results.length; i++) {
  myAddress[i] = myJSONResult.results[i].formatted_address;
}
---
how can i do the same in php?

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode($json_string)` to convert a json string to a variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Apple%20inc&key=');
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach($data->results as $result) {

    print '<h4>' . $result->formatted_address . '</h4>';
    print 'Lat: ' . $result->geometry->location->lat . ', ' . $result->geometry->location->lng . '<hr>';
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: hi .. i used simplexml_load_file instead of file_get_content. i was more interested in xml ... it works ... sometimes...eg
--
$xml = simplexml_load_file($google_url) or die("url not loading");
echo "googleurl ->" . $google_url . "<br>";
print_r($xml);
-
it works for 90% of requests ... but sometimes it doesn't work and can't understand why ...
if i pass (for example) the url ... https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Località Peziè, 118, 32043 CORTINA D'AMPEZZO, Italia&key=<myapykey> the result is INVALID_REQUEST ... if i copy and paste in a browser, it works properly ...why?

Comment: btw solved the last... problem was due to special chars in italian language